# Google Chrome sync: Is there a limit for bookmarks & extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-chrome-extensions, google-sync

Actually, Chrome is my favorite web-browser, and one of its most powerful features is synchronizing the actual data into a Google account. For the last years I gained a lot of bookmarks and from time to time browse the extensions gallery to find new valuable ones. Really, synchronizing between my work and home PC's freed me from manual sync.

And for the recent months I experience strange glitches. I guess it may be caused by a lot of stored bookmarks (potentially about 3K [in estimate], but please don't ask why **:)**) and extensions (about 130 installed but only 10-15 daily used). I can mention the following strange things:

- Recently added bookmarks sometimes are not synchronized (e.g. I put a bookmark at work, but it's not guaranteed I can see it that evening), despite `about:sync` indicates a good sync process.
- Sometimes recently modified bookmarks appear in either (let's call) *last at home* or *last at work* bookmark folders.
- Sometimes bookmarks are not synced at all. (Moreover, Chromium versions may even crash)
- Extensions are not synced now at all.
- Perhaps, there's another reason, but *Google Mail Checker* and *Google Reader Notifier* do not show indicators of incoming e-mails and news.
- ...

I'm not sure but it looks like I might exceed Chrome internal sync limits... Is it right? Are there any workarounds, or should I make a massive bookmarks/extensions cleanup (I really don't want it **:(**)?

I mostly use Google Chrome Canary builds, and the my current one is *12.0.732.0*.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update #1 (2011-04-19)**:
I removed about 50 extensions that I'm not interested in (or that I consider as trash), and gained pretty some results:

- The extensions count is below 100 (exactly 97);
- The `chrome://extensions` page does not get slow (or even frozen) any more on enabling/disabling/uninstalling extensions;
- The extensions are seem to be synchronized now again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Chrome's internal sync, but you might try [XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) sync.  It offers sync between browsers as well as computers across the internet.  It supports all 4 major browsers.  You can also access your bookmarks from any computer via their web portal, in case you find yourself on another computer and need access to your bookmarks.  And if you upgrade to their pay service, you can sync to your iPhone, Blackberry or Android device as well and gain access to their open tab sync, where you can close your browser on one computer, go to another computer, open up the browser and all the tabs you had open will be opened on the new computer.

Comment: Thank you for reply, BBlake. XMarks is a good tool, but it does not meet my requirements exactly. First of all, Google synchronization mechanism is out of box and allows sync the bookmarks using my Google account. Second, it also syncs Chrome extensions as well.